# IBM Worklight Adapter - Algorithm for JSON Conversion

Tags: json, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

As per the adapter framework explanation [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html)

The IBM Worklight Server will automatically covert the response coming from the Back-end to JSON.
I need to know which algorithm the IBM Worklight Server using to convert the back end data to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific algorithm, it is just plain format conversion. e.g.

```
<a>
  <b>
    c
  </b>
</a>
```

will become

```
{ 
    a: { 
         b: "c" 
       }
}
```